# Check if app was launched from a notification or icon?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am implementing FCM notifications and I have a notification coming from my backend which does not contain any data, just a title. This means that **if my app is *not* running** while this notification arrives, and the user opens this notification, my app will be launched with null extras and data in its intent.

Is there a way to differentiate this "empty notification" launch from the normal "user tapped the the app icon" launch of the app so I can take the user to the "notifications" section of the app when needed?

Both cases have null data and extras in their intent.

Comment: Show your Notification service code. You can add a boolean flag there while opening activity to distinguish it from the normal app launch.

Comment: The service does not run when the notification arrives while the app is not running. The notification data are passed to the intent by the Android OS and not my custom FirebaseMessagingService.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `putExtra(ID_KEY,id)` when you create your Intent for starting your application, and in your `onCreate()` method you can use `getIntent().getExtras().getInt(ID_KEY)` to retrieve your passed id.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem here is not with notifications that are handled by my FirebaseMessagingService. Its with notifications that arrive while my app, and service, is not running, which are then delivered to the app via an intent when the user taps on the notification. That is the case i'm trying to differentiate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. What you can do is for each `Intent` specify its `action`. Like this:

```
private fun sendNotification(title: String, message: String) {
        // Firstly, you create an intent that will open an activity when user taps on your notification.
        val intent = Intent(this, ProfileScreenActivity::class.java)
            .putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_FIREBASE_MESSAGE_TITLE, title) // Add Title
            .putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_FIREBASE_MESSAGE_BODY, message) // Add Message
        
        // Optional, but it basically clears backstack and all hierarchy of open Fragments/Activities
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

        // Here is where we specify that this Intent comes from Firebase Service
        intent.action = INTENT_ACTION_FIREBASE_MESSAGE_DIALOG

        // Wrap all of this
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        // Standard code for creating and sending Notifications.
        val channelId = getString(R.string.firebase_default_notification_channel_id)
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        notificationManager.notify(Random.nextInt(0, 100), notificationBuilder.build())
    }
```

Then inside your Activity that you're opening when user taps on your Notification, you do the following:

```
// Check if any actions were passed to this Activity when it's started.
// If any actions were passed, we check what action was passed and proceed from there.
    intent.action?.let { action ->
                if (action == INTENT_ACTION_FIREBASE_MESSAGE_DIALOG) {
                    intent.extras?.let { extras ->
                        alertDialog.warning(this, extras.getString(INTENT_EXTRA_FIREBASE_MESSAGE_BODY), extras.getString(INTENT_EXTRA_FIREBASE_MESSAGE_TITLE))
                    }
                }
    
                if (action == INTENT_ACTION_INTERNET_DAYS_LEFT_DIALOG) {
                    intent.extras?.let { extras ->
                        alertDialog.warning(this, extras.getString(INTENT_EXTRA_INTERNET_DAYS_LEFT))
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. The problem here is not with notifications that are handled by my `FirebaseMessagingService`. Its with notifications that arrive while my app, and service, is not running, which are then delivered to the app via an intent when the user taps on the notification. That is the case i'm trying to differentiate.

Comment: @LucasP. Can you show me a code where you send the notifications that you're talking about?

Comment: They're sent from a backend server, which I do not have access to, these are not Local notifications.

Comment: You sending them via Firebase?

Comment: Yes, but our server is generating the notification and is passing them to Firebase. We can't change the notification's properties since it will crash older version of our app, so we need to be able to detect if the app was launched form an empty notification, or the App's Icon on the phone's launcher.

Comment: All the notifications that are received on the phone from Firebase are handles by `FirebaseMessagingService` so just use the code I provided and you will be able to achieve what you need

Comment: After working on this and testing it thoroughly, I think you are mistaken, as the docs also say. The Service won't be called if the app is in background or not running. The Android OS caches and handles the notification itself. Keep in mind that the notification is empty, it doesn't contain any data to be delivered to the service. I just need to know if the app was launched form it, or not. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#backgrounded

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Android delivers the whole notification bundle to the App's launch Intent *extras*. Our app had some code that was checking if a particular key existed in those extras, otherwise it was discarding them. This way we can check/add an action to the intent or a key/value pair to the extras to differentiate between a Notification Launch and an Icon Launch of the app, using something similar to what Priyaank and Rey suggested.

There is one common misconception about this topic. You need to keep in mind that the FirebaseMessagingService's `onMessageReceived` method will *not* get called if the app is in the background or killed. Android will deliver the notification to the launch Intent (extras), once the user clicks on the notification.